# Button content not updating using Frameworkelementfactory

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic

I have been trying to create a ContentTemplate using the lovely Frameworkelementfactory.

The code works except I can't set the content of the Button. I have tried many things but I always end up with a Button with Content= Button.

Here is the code which generates the contenttemplate. For your further info, I am using this in a Tabcontrol Header Itemtemplate...

Cheers.

```
ControlTemplate ct = new ControlTemplate(typeof(TabItem));

FrameworkElementFactory spouter = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof    (DockPanel));
FrameworkElementFactory text = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
text.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, Name);
spouter.AppendChild(text);

FrameworkElementFactory mButtonPrev = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
mButtonPrev.SetValue(System.Windows.Controls.Button.ContentProperty, "x");
mButtonPrev.AddHandler(System.Windows.Controls.Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(CloseTab));
spouter.AppendChild(mButtonPrev);
ct.VisualTree = spouter;
return ct;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ControlTemplate ct = new ControlTemplate(typeof(TabItem));
```

Shouldn't you be creating a `DataTemplate` here instead?

(Everything else looks fine to me, also [`FEF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx) is deprecated, read [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx))

Comment: Hi have read the docs. Its a TabItem and I'm setting the TabItem.Template which although in the XAML is of type Datatemplate I am unable to cast to Datatemplate. Using Controltemplate sort of works! Using Xaml.load is really slow and also can't be cast. And yes I have read it is deprecated. But why should the handler work but not the content?

Answer (score 0):

For those of use still using FEF, I was able to set the content of my button with the actual string. I see Name as where "button" is coming from in your example. In my example, Name pulls up the class name that I'm binding to my datagrid.

```
    var buttonTemplate = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
    var text = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
    text.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "Save");
    buttonTemplate.AppendChild(text);
    buttonTemplate.AddHandler(
        System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.ClickEvent,
        new RoutedEventHandler((o, e) => MessageBox.Show("hi"))
    );

    AccountDatagrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTemplateColumn()
    {
        Header = "Save",
        CellTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = buttonTemplate }
    });
    AccountDatagrid.ItemsSource = AccoutDescCodeTime.GetBaseAccounts();
```